Does the LEGO Answers site get credit for hats earned by the users that opted out of the "Winter Bash" promotion?
I was checking out the Hat leaderboard. We are currently holding 89 of them. Does the site get credit for hats earned by the LEGO Answers users that met the criteria to earn a hat, but opted out of the "Winter Bash" promotion?


At the bottom of every page, there is a button labeled, "I Hate Hats!"
  This will turn off all hat-related events on all sites for you. You
  won't see people wearing hats, you won't be alerted when you earn a
  hat, and you won't be seen wearing a hat by any other users.

I believe all the 'I Hate Hats!' button does, is disable the javascript that displays hats on the site. Your username is removed from the leaderboards but the total hats remain the same. Remember you can always opt-in and out whenever and as often as you like.

Thanks! Have a Fez on me.... ;)
